# the best way to pinch to zoom an imageview

Tags: java, android, xml, imageview

What is the best way to pinch-to-zoom an imageview in Android, because i've been searching this for a long long time. Is there some tutorial, or example ? I just want some tips to guide me in the right direction.

Comment: E.g. http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-6-implementing-the-pinch-zoom-gesture/1847

Answer (score 1):

you can use `scalegesturedetector` see here http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want more fine grained control you can subclass `ImageView` handle the touch events and directly manipulate the matrix of the canvas backing it during your `onDraw` calls.

It's a lot more complex but for my project it turned out to be the best solution.